# Migrate Django models to external database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to set up an environment where users will be able to provide authentication for their SQL databases and allow me to run queries. Is there a way to migrate a Django model that I have designed onto their database?
For example, I would have a Django model that stores their authentication info:

```
class Oracle(models.Model):
    host = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
    user = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
    pass = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
    ...
```

And I would want to migrate and manage this model on their DB:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(maxlength=20)
    ...
```

How do I generate the query code to create the table, and everything else Django models can provide (retrieve, modify, etc.)?

Comment: You just use migrations, as usual?

Comment: You probably need to dig in a direction of db routers for queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/ For migrations it sounds like you need at the very least write your custom migration https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/writing-migrations/#data-migrations-and-multiple-databases It's probably easier to just run a raw sql to create the required tables